# Why is setState printing out the final state value only in the functional setState?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

class Add extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount called');
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        console.log('componentDidUpdate called');
    }

    increment() {

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            count: prevState.count + 1
        }), () => {
            console.log('callback ' + this.state.count)
        });

        console.log('not a callback ' + this.state.count);
    }

    incrementFive() {
        this.increment();
        this.increment();
    }

    render() {
        console.log('render called');
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>count is {this.state.count}.</h2>
                <button onClick={() => this.incrementFive()}>Increment</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Add;
```

click `Increment` button. console logs:

```
not a callback. count: 0
not a callback. count: 0
render called
componentDidUpdate called
callback. count: 2  //why is it 2 here instead of 1
callback. count: 2
```

I was expecting:

```
not a callback. count: 0
not a callback. count: 0
render called
componentDidUpdate called
callback. count: 1 
callback. count: 2
```

I understand `setState` behaves in async way, but I couldn't understand why `setState` only prints the final state value in the callback. If we provide a callback, it is executed right after the state is updated. Here when we click `Increment` button, the `count` is set to 1 and the callback should have printed out `count: 1`, but I see its only printing the final state value, i.e `2`.

Answer (score 0):

the setState only print the final state because you are not awaiting the async call `setState`
check the code below i have used async await

```
async incrementFive() {
   await this.increment();
   await this.increment();
}
```

It will print both values now